# M-w breaks intermittently on Windows 10

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows

`M-w` stops working randomly on my Windows 10, which I believe is the same issue described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2tt4l5/mw_seemingly_randomly_does_not_work/). Unfortunately no solutions can be found.

To sum up:

1. `M` is mapped to `Alt`
2. The problem occurs to **ALL** Emacs installations, i.e. as a native Windows app, an app in the WSL subsystem, and native linux app in a Putty session.
3. The problem occurs randomly, but once it appears, the only solution is a system reboot.
4. Other shortcuts like `M-x` or `ESC-w` work

Any ideas?

Comment: Please summarize here the information that you link to on Reddit - make the question more self-contained.

Comment: I think the four points I listed are already pretty clear. Could you please elaborate on how to make it more self-contained?

Comment: In general 'stopped working' is not informative enough. Describe what happens. For a shortcut problem, also include what happens when you try it with 'C-h k'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me. I was able to find an application named QQ (by closing one after another) that registers the shortcut `Alt-w` and prevents all other programs from receiving the key combination.

Just a side note, telling from [this SO answer](https://superuser.com/a/191090/352206), it might be impossible to get what process actually registered a shortcut for Windows 8 and above.